# Orders Collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2

my objective is to find all orders with status "pending".

Seems the way to do this is to use the Order\Collection

```
class Modelx extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    /**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $salesOrderCollectionFactory;


public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $salesOrderCollectionFactory
) {

            $this->salesOrderCollectionFactory = $salesOrderCollectionFactory;

}


    public function getSalesOrderCollection(array $filters = [])
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $salesOrderCollection */
    $salesOrderCollection = $this->salesOrderCollectionFactory->create();

    foreach ($filters as $field => $condition) {

        $salesOrderCollection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }

    return $salesOrderCollection->load();
}
```

}

I'm passing  status='pending' to the filter which seems to be working.

```
$return = $this->_model->getSalesOrderCollection( array('status' => 'Pending'));
```

From $return I like to retrieve the order ids but not sure how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The recommended way to retrieve stored data is with Repository and not Factoies, consider that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get ids then add **getAllIds()** which is *`give array of order ids`*.

If want to fetch increment ids then add  ***getColumnValues('fieldName')*** to collection.So for this case,you can use

**`$Increment_ids=$collection->getColumnValues('increment_id')`**

**AddtionaL:**

If you want use by view then try this:

```
<?php
namespace 'YourmoduleNameSpace';

class Modelx extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
  /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')

    }
   public function getSalesOrderCollection(array $filters = []){
    foreach ($filters as $field => $condition) {

        $this->orderCollectionFactory->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }

    return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
}       
}
```

Comment: How to get sales order collection in magento 2 custom admin grid with order-status filter

Comment: Could you add an example on how to use it from here in the template or further on? Like selecting a specific customer ID? :-)

Comment: hey $Amit, can you tell how to apply visibility(products) filter on sales_order collection ? I am getting parant products as well, in case of configurable products.

Answer (score 6):

We should use Service Contracts Layer.

`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository` and `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder` are used for getting the order items with the conditions.

The construct method:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $orderRepository;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 *  Constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
)
{
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}
```

In our custom method:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter(
       'status',
       'pending',
       'eq'
    )->create();

    $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
            //Your code here
    };
```