# M2 Circular dependency: CalculateOrders\Metric depends on CalculateOrders\Metric and vice versa

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

how can I fix this error ?

```
**Circular dependency**:
```

`Heckfy\Health\Model\Metrics\CalculateOrders\Metric depends on Heckfy\Health\Model\Metrics\CalculateOrders\Metric`

and vice versa

I have class metric manager where I try to init my metric object like this:

```
$this->metric = $this->objectManager->create('Heckfy\Health\Model\Metrics\CalculateOrders\Metric');
```

I guess the problem in my metric class:

```
class Metric extends AbstractMetric
{
 public $collectionFactory;
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Because without constructor it works well.
I tried debug it and found this part of code inside method create().

```
if (isset($this->creationStack[$requestedType])) {
            $lastFound = end($this->creationStack);
            $this->creationStack = [];
            throw new \LogicException("Circular dependency: {$requestedType} depends on {$lastFound} and vice versa.");
        }
```

Looks like magento already init this class and put it to $this->creationStack. But how?

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you share the AbstractMetric class code ? Never use objectManager but DI also.

Comment: AbstractMetric is empty, actually it was added for future

Comment: I tried do like here is : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95608/orders-collection-magento-2 but I don't need extend \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Answer (score 1):

I've discussed with M2 experienced developer and He recommend me not using objectManager when we want create new object because it's bad practise. Instead of objectManager

```
$this->metric = $this->objectManager->create('Heckfy\Health\Model\Metrics\CalculateOrders\Metric');
```

we can inject this class in our constructor.

I hope it will be useful for somebody who just started learning M2